# How to show all current locks in hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am a newbie for Hazelcast. I would like to know how can I list current lock in Hazelcast console?

For ex. assume that i open three console and i have taken 3 lock as follow:

```
m.lock object1
m.lock object2
m.lock object3
```

How can i get output like:

```
number of lock site: 3
locks: object1, object2, object3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console is just a test app to simulate basic functionalities of hazelcast.

To see your lock instances following code will help you.

```
HazelcastInstance hzInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(null);
Collection<Instance> instances = hzInstance.getInstances();
Set<Instance> locks = new HashSet<Instance>();
for (Instance inst : instances) {
    if(inst.getInstanceType().equals(Instance.InstanceType.LOCK))
    locks.add(inst);
}
```

Comment: What is the curent way to do this in hazelcast-3.6 version? As far as I can  see getInstances method seems to be removed from HazelcastInstance...

Comment: Now it is `hzInstance.getDistributedObjects()`

Answer (score 0):

With Hazelcast 3.X we have to use `hz.getDistributedObjects()`.

Please refer [Renaming "instance" to "distributed object"](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.0/manual/html/ch01s02.html) for more details.