# How to show all structure names in hazelcast 3.x

Tags: java, hazelcast

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797671/), but it's 2 years ago and for previous version, not works in hz 3.x.So, my question is how to achieve this in hz 3.x ?

Like APP1 open lock 1, APP2 open lock 2, how can I know the all lock that already taken ?

Comment: So how's your question differs from the original one?  If it is just the same, I'd rather treat this as a duplicated question

Comment: The original question can not answer this question, but the requirement is same, so I should post the answer to original question ?

Comment: you found a previous question, and you said your question is the same as it, and that question already got an accepted answer, then why that accepted answer cannot solve your question then?  You gotta be clear.  If the case is you have another way to solve the same question, post it in the original question.  If turns out your question or requirement is different from that original one, state that clearly in your question.

Comment: Because the version changed,that question is about 2 years ago,the answer not works any more.so I append `in hazelcast 3.x` in the title.What should I do ?

Comment: Then just mention in your question that the solution in that similar question is no longer working in Hazelcast 3.  It is just confusing for you to mention that question with accepted answer, without telling why it is not working

Comment: Thanks @AdrianShum, I updated the question and I will mention this next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way with many tricks,works with any service

Run svr first, then run cli and test.

```
public class PlayHZ
{
    @Test
    public void test() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException
    {
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        IExecutorService executor = hz.getExecutorService("gather");
        Map<Member, Future<List<String>>> futures = executor.submitToAllMembers(new LockNameGather());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Found in member");
        for (Map.Entry<Member, Future<List<String>>> entry : futures.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.printf("%s -> %s\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void svr() throws InterruptedException
    {
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Test
    public void cli() throws InterruptedException
    {
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            ILock lock = hz.getLock("LOCK" + i);
            lock.lock();
        }
        Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    private static class LockNameGather implements Callable<List<String>>, HazelcastInstanceAware, Serializable
    {
        transient HazelcastInstance hz;
        transient NodeEngineImpl node;

        @Override
        public List<String> call() throws Exception
        {
            node = ((HazelcastInstanceImpl) hz).node.getNodeEngine();
            LockService svc = node.getService(LockService.SERVICE_NAME);

            return svc.getAllLocks()
                      .stream()
                      .map(LockResource::getKey)
                      .map(d -> node.getSerializationService().createObjectDataInput(d))
                      .map((r) -> {
                          try
                          {
                              return r.readUTF();
                          } catch (IOException e)
                          {
                              throw new RuntimeException(e);
                          }
                      }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        @Override
        public void setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance)
        {
            hz = hazelcastInstance;
        }
    }
}
```