# Hazelcast how to get all current locks?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I need to see all the locks in the Hazelcast cluster.

I know that this question has been asked below:

[How to show all current locks in hazelcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797671/how-to-show-all-current-locks-in-hazelcast#)

But , as far as I can see getInstances method seems to be removed from HazelcastInstance.

What is the correct way to do this in hazelcast-3.6 version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Hazelcast 3.x you'll make use of the common super interface DistributedObject

```
Collection<DistributedObject> objects = hazelcastInstance.getDistributedObjects();
for (DistributedObject object : objects) {
  if (object instanceof ILock) {
    handleLock((ILock) object);
  }
}
```

However, this only works for locks created by `hazelcastInstance.getLock(...)` but not with key-locks created through the `IMap` interface.

Comment: Thnx. Is there a way to get locks created through the IMap.lock() method  ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry. If necessary, please file a feature request on github :)

Comment: note that this only works with `ILock`, not with `FencedLock`